# How to create a predicate in Prolog with placeholder?

Tags: prolog

Well, I want to create several predicates during the prolog process, without reusing the names among them. For example, I would like to create N predicates: pred1, pred2, ..., predN.

It might work that using a recursive method to generate N predicates by calling asserta/1 or assertz/1, but how about naming every predicate with a placeholder? (That is, I want to name these predicates as pred1, pred2, ... predN). Is there any method in prolog to work with this? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Are you sure you cannot just add a parameter and have one predicate?

Comment: @DanielLyons I am implementing the code based on the paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.02693.pdf). Basically, the algorithm tries to find a rule that satisfies the given positive examples and rules out the negative ones, and a new predicate will be announced if we find out some rules that cover the examples, and there might be several rules to be generated.